# How to have multiple connections to a Arduino webserver?

Tags: http, arduino, webserver, ip-address

I have an Arduino running a webserver that is receiving data every 2 seconds. I CAN connect to its IP address by typing into the browser. I also created a web app that pulls data from this IP address every time new data comes in. The issue is that I need to access the IP address with the web app while another program is accessing it. Currently only one program can access at a time. I would like to have a Python script pulling data from the IP address constantly and still allow the web app to connect to view it live. How can I achieve this?

Arduino code with a lot of other stuff removed...

```
WiFiServer server(80);            //server socket
WiFiClient client_1 = server.available();
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  enable_WiFi(); // function to enable wifi
  connect_WiFi(); // function to connect to wifi

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  client_1 = server.available();
  if (client_1) {
    printWEB(client_1); // this posts the data as text to the web IP address
  }
  delay(2000);
}

void printWEB(WiFiClient client) {

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");   
            client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
            client.println("Content-type: application/json");
            client.println();
           
            moistureReading = analogRead(A1);
            
            tmpString = dataPosted;
            tmpString.replace("%moistureData%", String(moistureReading) );
            
            client.flush();
            client.print( tmpString ); 
            
            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
            client.println();
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          }
          else {      // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        }
        else if (c != '\r') {    // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    // close the connection:    
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok your not posting to an IP Address lets get that clear, you have a "server" that is located at an IP Address. To even give you the slightest help we will have to know what type of server you have. What operating system it's running on "if it is". Also is the server on an Arduino or a computer?

Comment: Yes this is an arduino mkr 1010 wifi. The server is hosted via the WiFiServer() and WiFiClient(). Is this as simple as opening 2 ip address on the device?

Comment: OK hang on, I just reread your comment! is this the same Arduino that you're using to upload data and the one that is running the webserver the same Arduino? By the way, if you could then please add the code to your question.

Comment: Ya just to clarify, I am opening a wifi server at a specified ip address on the arduino. It then sends data to this ip address via wifi. Outside of the arduino I have a web app that collects this data. I can only connect to the IP address via a single connection. If I try to run a separate program to this ip address while the app is running, it will not open. I have tried something as simple as using PC to open IP address in browser and continually refresh, then try to open IP address via phone and it wont work. If I stop refreshing the PC, the phone connects. It cant handle multiple requests

Comment: Does that make sense? Ip address can't handle more than 1 incoming request. I am not sure code will help in this situation as everything works fine. It is simply an IP address question.

Comment: Weird, No it should handle all incoming requests, no matter where it's from. In the order they are received.

Comment: it does, but not simultaneously. Should it handle those too?

Comment: Ok, correct it can only talk to one IP at a time, but it should switch between clients so fast that it "seems" like it was simultaneous. Please share your code as it is kinda difficult for me to follow along here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224543/discussion-between-edgar-wideman-and-justin-oberle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to take the delay off of the arduino code by simply removing the sleep function (Turns out this is not required). I then had to create a delay in all of my fetching codes. The React.js needed a sleep function and the python script needed a sleep function. This allows the two platforms to collect data from the same IP Address simultaneously. I needed a minimum of about 5-10 second sleep for both apps in order for this to work. I initially tried 1 second for each and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The webserver as programmed on your Arduino can only serve one request from a client at a time, not two simultaneously.

If two clients are doing requests in a loop, and are doing that fairly quickly, there will be situations where one client is blocking access for the other.

Try making the two clients much slower, i.e. retrieve information at a much lower frequency, just to see if the Arduino can keep up then.

Also, make the webserver on the Arduino as fast as possible, and call it as often as possible.

So, don't put `delay()`s in the loop, or anywhere else, and try to do the `analogread()` and the return string preparation outside of the webserver code and in the `loop()` every x seconds using `millis()`, so as little time as possible is spent in the webserver code.